# CoreData objects not getting unfaulted

Tags: core-data, restkit

In an iOS6 app I fetch NSManagedObjects from DB with CoreData and display them in a tableViewCell. My problem is, that all objects that correspond to cells outside of the initial scroll position are in fault state and do not come back to life. I can't see my mistake.

fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO; helps, but I want a clean solution.

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContactsCell";
    ContactsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Contact *contact = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //here some contacts are faulted. contact.name is null if I fetch it

    [cell setContactData:contact];

    return cell;
}
```

here is how I fetch (with Restkit 0.10.3):

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [Contact fetchRequest];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [self sortDescriptors];
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
    return [Contact objectsWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I never really used your approach so I won't say that it is wrong, but I'll say that it is strange. I guess that Contact is a subclass of NSManagedObject, and I can believe that it knows of the fetch request which which he was originally fetched, and that he knows of the context from which he was fetched, but only after he was already fetched. I really don't see how could he know of those things if he never before was fetched from the persistent store. So I recommend U use classic executeFetch or fetchedResultsController to populate your tableView.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]; 
[context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [self sortDescriptors];
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
return array;
```

Try it, hope it helps

Comment: [Contact objectsWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest]; is an extension by Restkit 0.10.x. With 0.20 they dropped that code, developers now have to use the Core Data syntax.